# LinkedIn api - How to retrieve Update Engagement data?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I've been searching all over the place, but I just can't find an api call that returns data from analytics -> updates -> Update engagement

I'm trying to retrieve data from this part of LinkedIn, see the screenshot:
[image]

I'll appreciate any help! I cant find it for the life of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics#share-statistics-data-schema

seemed to be the best fit. "reactions" are translated to "likeCount" and certain attributes are missing such as video views and ctr

edit: It seemed to be a lot more work than expected.

First i used an api key with the scope `r_organization_social` for  `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/sharesq=owners&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{organizationid}`

Then, use the ID's of that result in:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:{organizationID}&shares[0]=urn:li:share:id1&shares[1]=urn:li:share:id2` (For multiple ids)

however, you need an api key with a different scope for that, i used `rw_organization_admin` (Create a key with 2 scopes). Also the header should only contain the authorization bearer

Comment: Hi, I am also stucked with the same issue. were you able to get the Update engagement API endpoint? I tried couple of ways, but couldn't get much success. I am looking for - **Update Title, Update Link, Update type, Posted By, Create Date, Audience, Impression, views, Click, click through rate, likes, comment, share, Follows, Engagement , Content type**. Could you please guide me on this? Appreciate your Help. Thanks!

Comment: how would I get engagement data for user posts? via the users timeline, if I have the post id from the post api call?

Comment: @sac Have to got a way to get CTR ?